# Monitor MPSSH Progress, maybe PV?

Tags: ssh, bandwidth, parallelism

Does anyone know of a good way to monitor the progress of `mpssh`?  While making a large number of parallel connections it can take some time to complete.  I'm trying to figure out a good way to monitor mpssh's OVERALL progress (e.g., a single progress bar that runs until all hosts are processed in the hosts file).

The closest I've come is: `mpssh -f hosts -u root date | pv`

Which outputs a single progress bar that IS NOT updated (other than a running clock):

```
0 B 0:00:03 [   0 B/s] [<=>
```

Once all hosts in the file are processed the full output comes back:

```
192.168.1.1 -> Thu Jun  1 23:24:44 UTC 2017                                                  
192.168.1.2 -> Thu Jun  1 23:24:44 UTC 2017
192.168.1.3 -> Thu Jun  1 23:24:44 UTC 2017
```

and the last line is the closing progress bar

```
213 B 0:00:08 [25.7 B/s] [ <=>
```

The last line in this case doesn't do more than `time`. So I'd like to be able to see the progress bar that is displayed initially, but also have it update after each host is processed — display the overall progress.